# php eval and pg_execute not working! arg

Tags: php, postgresql, eval

What am I missing? I am building a dynamic query and preparing the query for postgres. It should work but the eval statement does not do it's magic.  What am I missing?

Is there another way to pass a string with multiple variables besides the eval? Thanks.

The brief explanation.

```
$condition = array();
$values    = array();
$pgarray   = array();

$country = 254;
$city    = "Seattle";

$condition[] = " AND city = $";
$values[]    = $city;
$pgarray[]   = "\$city";

$condition[] = " AND country = $";
$values[]    = $country;
$pgarray[]   = "\$country";

$as = sizeof($condition);

for ( $x=0; $x<$as; $x++ ) {
   $index = $x + 1;  //We need to start at one not 0
   $qclause = $qclause . $condition[$x] . $index . "  ";
}

// This is what qclause equates to.
// AND city = $1 AND country = $2 

$pgarray = implode(", ", $pgarray);

// This is what pgarray equated to.
// $city, $country

$query  = "Select companyid, city, name from company where 1 = 1 $qclause";
$result = pg_prepare($dbconnect, 'q1', $query);
$runthis = "pg_execute(\$dbconnect, 'q1', array($pgarray) )";


// This is what $runthis equated to.
// pg_execute($dbconnect, 'q1', array($city, $country) )

$result = eval($runthis);

While ..... {
   bla bla bla
}
```

Oh, I have also done

```
$result = eval('return $runthis');
```

No errors are generated. The prepare gets logged in postgres log file but the pg_execute never happens.

Am I missing something really obvious ?

Thanks

JT

Comment: Why on earth are you using `eval()` for this? Are you inviting hackers to claim your server as their own? Use *prepared statements* and dont use `eval()`

Comment: @Xorifelse That is what the eval is doing. Generating prepared statements dynamically.  The probblems is that I cannot seem to pass the separated list of variables into thee array of pg_execute. Regardless, if you look at the examples and the code, you will see the goal is a prepared ststement. Eventually, those variables will be retrieved from $_POST instead of the test variables in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
$pgarray[]   = "\$city";
$pgarray[]   = "\$country";
```

TO

```
$pgarray[]   = $city;
$pgarray[]   = $country;
```

And

```
$runthis = "pg_execute(\$dbconnect, 'q1', array($pgarray) )";
```

TO

```
$result = pg_execute($dbconnect, 'q1', $pgarray );
```

And it solved the problem or should I say my buggy code.